# can we change block title using template_preprocess_block?

Tags: views, 8, hooks

I am having a need to dynamically change the title of a block. Here is what I am trying but no avail.

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['elements']['#id'] == "views_block__weekly_schedule_all_blocks_block_2") {

    //$variables['elements']['content']['#title']['#markup'] = "Foobar";

    //$variables['elements']['content']['#title'] = 'foibar';
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [`block_example.module`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example%21block_example.module/group/block_example/8.x-1.x). It's [`hook_block_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/8.2.x) you can use to do this programmatically. You can probably use it in a `*.theme` as well.

Source [`block_example_block_view_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example%21block_example.module/function/block_example_block_view_alter/8.x-1.x).

```
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;

function MYMODULE_block_view_alter(array &$build, BlockPluginInterface $block) {

  // We'll search for the string 'uppercase'.
  $definition = $block
    ->getPluginDefinition();
  if (!empty($build['#configuration']['label']) && mb_strpos($build['#configuration']['label'], 'uppercase') || !empty($definition['subject']) && mb_strpos($definition['subject'], 'uppercase')) {

    // This will uppercase the block title.
    $build['#configuration']['label'] = mb_strtoupper($build['#configuration']['label']);
  }
}
```

---

Most often you find answers to questions like that really fast when you google for *Drupal X how to X programmatically* or similar.

Answer (score 0):

`$variables['label'] = 'My label';`

Source: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/8.2.x